# Changing field type

Tags: jquery

How to change drop-down field on html page to input type=text.

I used j query but it doesn't work, here's my snippet

```
$("[name=checkload1_c]").prop('type','text');
```

checkload1_c is name of drop down on field

Comment: Is your dropdown field a `<select>` HTML tag then?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a dropdown (`<select>`) into editable like this. But you can use some JavaScript libraries for that instead. Editable drop down is also called `Combobox`. you can try google for combobox libraries. Few examples are :-

- [Editable_select](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/form_widget_editable_select/form_widget_editable_select.html)
- [Combobox](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxcombobox/jquery-combobox-getting-started.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I wouls suggest replacing the element instead of changing it, something like this code:

https://jsfiddle.net/s1pwkrpd/

```
$("button").click(function() {
    replace("checkload1_c") //execute the replacement
})

function replace(name) {
  $input = $("<input>", {type:"text", name:name}) //create a new element with same name
  $("[name=" + name + "]").replaceWith($input) //replace the old element
}
```